# Rtree Quadratic Split example understand

Tags: database, indexing, tree, r-tree

Can someone explain me how the distance for the quadratic split here is being calculated for this example, and if you could suggest me more examples, it would be really helpful for me. Thank you

[image: Example of the R-tree]

Answer (score 0):

I think those quadratic split distances shown are considering the squares to be 1X1, not 10X5. The idea is to find how much space would be wasted in a bounding box that covered the two rectangles - for example, a bounding box covering R1 and R2 would be 4X2, area 8. Subtract 2 for the area of R1 and R2 - the wasted space is 6. Choose as seeds the two rectangles you would least want together, i.e. the two with the greatest wasted space.

This is explained in the original paper: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs764-1/rtree.pdf.

You can make up your own split algorithm. How good it is will affect the efficiency of the R-tree, but not the correctness.